# Unity attack once during animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Since I am still very beginner question maybe dumb but I am really cant find any solution. I am creating 3rd person adventure game and trying to implement enemy attack. The problem is that I cannot implement it in a way that enemy do damage only once during attack animation. In my code alreadyAttacked bool is changing to false only when the transitions between animations happens. However I want to reset this value everytime when the attack animation starts or finish.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, playerMask);
    playerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attackRange, playerMask);

    if (!playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) Patroling();
    if (playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) Chasing();
    if (playerInSightRange && playerInAttackRange) Attacking();
}

private void Attacking()
{
    animator.SetInteger("Condition", 2);
    agent.SetDestination(player.position);

    if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 0.4f 
        && animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime < 0.6f 
        && alreadyAttacked == false)
    {
        player.GetComponent<Health>().healthValue -= damage / 100f;

        alreadyAttacked = true;
    } 

    if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 0.7f )
    {
        alreadyAttacked = false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1597375/how-to-make-an-attack-animation-play-once.html

Answer (score 0):

You might rather want to look into [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html).

Without having to query states from the `Animator` you can rather simply invoke certain events directly from your animation state itself!

Simply rather make it

```
public void CauseDamage()
{
    if(player) player.GetComponent<Health>().healthValue -= damage / 100f;
}
```

and then in your animation itself add an Event

[image]

and select the method you want to call in the Event's inspector.

Then everytime your animation passes that key frame the event will be Invoked exactly once.